# Python error while working with class - Unbound method

Tags: python, class

I am trying to create a class with multiple functions, accepts a string as an argument and prints this string. So far this is what I have written:

```
class test():    
    def func(self,text):  
        print str(text)  
test.func('This is a bunch of text')
```

To which I get the following error message:

```
_Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
TypeError: unbound method func() must be called with test instance as first argument   (got str instance instead)_
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to instantiate a class before you can call an instance method:

```
class Test(object):
    def func(self, text):
        print str(text)

test = Test()
test.func('This is a bunch of text')
```

Comment: Thanks. You wouldn't happen to have a reference/link to someone intuitively explaining why this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try -

```
class test():
    @staticmethod
    def func(text):
        print str(text)
test.func('This is a bunch of text')
```

Comment: In general many people avoid staticmethods in Python because they're a good indication you didn't want a method at all but just a plain function.